# OnClick doesn't fire in custom Button class but in parent class

Tags: android, button, onclick, parent-child

I created my Own Button

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        ...></ImageView>

    <ImageView
        ...></ImageView>

    <TextView
        ...></TextView>
</merge>
```

her is the class for my Button

```
public class StandardButton extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener{
    ...

private void init(Context context){
        this.setClickable(true);
        this.setEnabled(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_button, this);

    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLabel("Click");
        }
```

the onClick function don't work. But it works if i put the Button in my Activity an override the onClick function.

**Is there a Solution to fire a function when the Button is clicked in my StandardButton class. This class should know if it's clicked or not, not the activity!**

Comment: It might be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve or more directly, why the regular Android button implementation doesn't do what you want/need it too.  Experimenting/Learning is a completely acceptable answer. :)

Comment: you can see the benefit very easily. The standard Button doesn't have 2 Imageview an 1 Textview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
this.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in the `init()` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

this.setFocusable(true);
```

these both line occuring error in your onclick event remove it and

PUT IT

```
this.setFocusable(false);
```

onclick will be working